# Pass data to ionic2 menu

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am having a menu whose html i have written in app.html-

```
<ion-menu [content]="mycontent">
  <ion-toolbar class = "menuUserName">
    <ion-title>{{userName}}</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      ...
     </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav #mycontent [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

My app flow is login->homepage.
when the user login the app,it will get username from a service.
How can i pass this data to my ionic2 menu to update username.

Comment: Define localStorage or sessionStorage to store the username and use it the required component.

Comment: i used localstorage,its not working.when we rae bootstrapping our app,that is the only time menu is added.menucontroller open and close will just show and hide menu,it will not reload app.ts .

Comment: You must be having a component to call a service which helps the user to pass through the login and give you the username from the database. In the promise of the service create a localstorage. Angular2 doesn't have the concept of controllers. Why do you have controllers?

Comment: menucontroller is ionic component name.BTW,what is my issue is that i am calling service from loginPage Component,which returns me user name.Now i need to pass that user name to menu which is part of app.ts,the file which is bootstrapped.NOW are you able to understand the issue?

Comment: i see you are binding `{{userName}}`, why don't you just update that in the component when you get the username? the menu should update automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is passing data between pages. I think you should use [Ionic Events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/)

for sending and responding to application-level events across your app.

For example: put it in app.ts

```
function createUser(user) {
    console.log('User created!')
    events.publish('user:created', user);
}

function listenToLoginEvents(){
      events.subscribe('user:created', (userEventData) => {
      console.log('Welcome', userEventData[0]);
      });
   }
```